# Will my Macbook Air be able to handle dual 4k displays?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a mid 2013 Macbook Air and I want to purchase two 4k monitors and hook it up to the MBA. Will my Macbook Air be able to hand the two monitors at it's full resolution?

If so, what cables would I need? If not, are there any macbook's that can handle dual 4k monitor at their native resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - No.

Longer answer, from [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i7-2.2-13-early-2015-specs.html)…

> *Although Apple only reports that this model can support a single external display up to 2560x1600, Intel reports that this model can simultaneously support two external displays up to 2560x1600 "daisy chained" via Thunderbolt 2.

The current top spec Macbook Pro, on the other hand, can support 2 external monitors at 4k, but only at 24Hz - same [source](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-3.1-13-early-2015-retina-display-specs.html)

> *This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 3840x2160 on two external displays via Thunderbolt 2. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 3840x2160 via Thunderbolt 2 and a single 1080p display at up to 60 Hz, 3840x2160 at 30 Hz, or 4096x2160 at 24 Hz via HDMI.